# disable rules on an automatically created fieldset?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can I disable rules on fieldset that's been created by .clone()? Note that the fields don't have the same names or Ids. Any luck someone has done this before.

The rules are created with [jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/).

Comment: Rules? What kind of rules?

Comment: Validation rules like input{required:true;}. I don't want it to follow up on the newly created fields

Comment: We're going to need some html and whatever else is part of the rules (css?)

Comment: I mean specifically jquery. I created everything and I clone perfectly. I style it perfectly. only issue is I would need to disable the validation rules I have on the new created fields. you guys can check my previous post with a sample  of the code [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449338/how-can-i-clone-a-fieldset-without-keeping-the-rules-of-the-fields)

Comment: `$("#excavationform").validate(...` where does that validate function come from? It's not part of the native jquery lib. Is it http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/ ?

Comment: $("#excavationform") is my form id that helps me validate my form's fields

Comment: Yes, I know. Where does the validate function come from? It's not part of jquery. And please use `@slicedtoad` in your messages or I may miss them.

Comment: @slicedtoad: yes that's native to jquery in oreder to put your rules.

Comment: No, it's not. http://jsfiddle.net/12s4fqv7/ Gives an `undefined is not a function` for the validate function call.

Comment: Please check out this[link](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) on internet. I don't know why the jsfiddle does not work but it works on my workstation @slicedtoad

Comment: It's a **jQuery Plugin**, not a native jQuery function. It's **3rd party**. This means you included **an additional script** (other than jquery) to get it to work.

Comment: alright! Gotcha now. So what do you think could be the problem? @slicedtoad

Comment: How can we possibly answer when you've shown us nothing?  My shortest answer to this is "don't add the rules to the cloned elements in the first place"... and I could show you exactly how if I knew what you were doing.

Comment: Quote: _"Validation rules like `input{required:true;}`"_  ~ There is no such thing as you cannot assign rules to any/all `input` elements like that.  That method only allows you to assign the rule to a _unique_ `name` attribute... and in that case, it's impossible to carry over to any clones with different `name` attributes.  You are going to have to show us some code before I write an answer... I'm not going to waste time guessing what you've done wrong.

Comment: Please do not post the same question more than once.  I'll look at [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449338/how-can-i-clone-a-fieldset-without-keeping-the-rules-of-the-fields) now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Workaround

Ok, so the problem is that cloning is not really supported by the validate plugin. Ideally, avoid it. But if you have to clone, this a workaround (not super robust).

http://jsfiddle.net/12s4fqv7/5/

```
//remove the rules and store them
var rules = [];
$("#f input").each(function(i){ // select each input in the form
    rules[i] = $(this).rules("remove"); // remove and save the rule
});

//clone
$("#f").clone().prop("id","f2").appendTo('body'); // clone it, change the id and do something with it.

//add rules back on
$("#f input").each(function(i){ // select each input again
    $(this).rules("add",rules[i]); // add the rule back
});
```

---

### Possible Alternative

Isntead of cloning, just copy the HTML and make a new jquery object:

```
var copy = $($('#form')[0].outerHTML).prop("id","newID")
```

This won't anything but the basic html.

---

### Old Answer

As far as I can tell, you are using the [jQuery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate your form.

Looking through it's [API](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/), you can remove rules with:

```
$( "#excavationform" ).rules( "remove" );
```

Please note, `.validate` is not a jquery method but a third party plugin. This should be mentioned in the question.

**Edit:**

`.rules("remove")` should be run on the clone. So,

```
$(clone).rules("remove"); // replace "clone" as needed
//or
```

Also, try it with `clone(true);`

```
$( "#excavationform" ).clone(true).rules("remove");
```

Comment: I tried but it does not work. Only adding rules works and not properly. It adds another rule on top of the rules from the section I repeated

Comment: @Pasoum Give me a sec, the above doesn't work yet.

Comment: Nope it is not working! @slicetoad

Comment: @Pasoum, when implemented properly, `.rules('remove')` is completely effective.  Please post the relevant code in your question.  How can you expect us to figure out why this is not working for your particular situation when we cannot see your code?

Comment: Hi @Sparky thanks for your reply. My code is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27449338/how-can-i-clone-a-fieldset-without-keeping-the-rules-of-the-fields). You can reply in there Thanks.

Comment: @Pasoum ok, try that. Might work. If not, try to replicate the error in jsfiddle and I can work from there.

Comment: Also, @Sparky here is how I added and removed rules: newElem.find('.dateChooser').each(function () {
   $(this).rules("add", {
    required: true
   });
  });
  newElem.find('.address').each(function () {
   $(this).rules("remove");
  });      Adding works (not properly as I want) and remove does nor work at all

Comment: @Pasoum, I am not going to engage in comments within somebody else's answer on the wrong page.  This one was closed.  Please answer my comments on your original page.

Comment: @Sparky Should I be moving this answer to that page?

Comment: slicetoad, of course feel free, although I think there's more to it, and until the OP posts the relevant HTML, I won't be posting any answers.